# extract information from database with SQL Injection

Tags: php, mysql, sql, web, code-injection

I have a website where I have to retrieve a password. I have only one form on the page, where I have to put the password. 
I tried "OR 1=1# and it told me "Authentication valid", but does not giving me the password, which I need.

Is there any way with SQL injection to "print" the password by writing the sql 
request directly in the form and not in the URL ?

Comment: print here the query you have

Answer (score 1):

The point is that you try to extract data from a process that do not actually show any data to the final user. Let me explain your vulnerable procedure is the **login process** which basically checks whether the user entered the right combination of username and password.

### Case 1

The query should be something like this:

```
select count(*) form users where username='$user', password='$password';
```

That query wont let you know anything about the user you're trying to hack, basically because it simply doesn't make any sense to do that during the login. The only thing you'll know for sure is the result: 1 or 0 of that query.

### Case 2 (non sense)

Is to have a query like this:

```
select username form users where username='$user', password='$password';
```

Let's assume that when you login the page tells you **username x** is not present in that database.
In that case you could be able to inject some malicious code in order to replace what is shown as **username** with arbitrary information about the database.

So you should have already understood that the answer to your question is no.